# Why confirm option of rails button_to helper is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rail button_to where I want it to show a confirm dialog box before proceeding.

```
<%= button_to("Rebuild indexes", action: "rebuild_indexes", data:
{confirm: "Are you sure you want to reset the indexes?" }) %>
```

The actions are occurring but I'm not getting a confirmation box. I read that the problem could be related to javascript. I thought I had that enabled.

```
application.js
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
//= require tinymce-jquery
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require ckeditor/config.js
//= require jquery.are-you-sure
//= require script
//= require script.responsive
//= require_tree .
```

If I do an inspect on the button, I see

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/help/rebuild_indexes?data%5Bconfirm%5D=Are+you+sure+you+want+to+reset+the+indexes%3F">
  <input type="submit" value="Rebuild indexes">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="3mnAMmyHaINiDngjQn87EMmhmetp2VJcX+lwcmbUlhwBfv7V1hpLc9ZY1OF5JAFm9erFJjX+qyDz35/KK41jaA==">
</form>
```

What am I missing in getting a confirmation box to appear?

Comment: did you try putting action in a hash?  <%= button_to("Rebuild indexes", {action: "rebuild_indexes"}, method: :post, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to reset the indexes?" }) %>

Comment: Is there anything in the server logs? How about the browser logs (usually in the Console tab)?

Comment: @ruby_newbie - the hash worked perfectly

Answer (score 24):

Just a quick note for those who want to create a button_to with confirmation text (in rails 7):

```
<%= button_to 'Rebuild indexes', action: :rebuild_indexes,
  form: {data: {turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?'}} %>
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar issue with the following line:

```
 <%= button_tag 'Delete', onclick: "location.href = #{polymorphic_url(obj)}", :method => :delete, type: 'button', class: 'btn btn-danger', title: 'Delete', id: 'delete_btn', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this record?' } %>
```

Removing "type: 'button'" fixed the confirm prompt issue

Answer (score 2):

`data: {confirm: "<confirm message>"}` is being tacked on to the url parameters hash instead of being passed as a third parameter - try separating the hashes like this:

```
button_to("Rebuild indexes", {action: "rebuild_indexes"}, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to reset the indexes?" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding link_to instead of button_to. '/indexes/rebuild' is the route.

```
<%= link_to "Rebuild indexes", '/indexes/rebuild', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to reset the indexes?' }, class:"btn btn-default" %>
```

Comment: `button_to` also supports that. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= button_to "/home/delete?cardId="+card.id.to_s, data: { confirm:'Are you sure you want to delete?' }  do %>
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
<% end%>
```

this generate

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/home/delete?cardId=15">
 <button data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete?" type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
 </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue with turbolink feature. You would need to explicitly turn off turbolink for the helper method, by insert 'turbolinks: false' into data attribute:

```
<%= button_to("Rebuild indexes", action: "rebuild_indexes", data:
{turbolinks: false, confirm: "Are you sure you want to reset the indexes?" }) %>
```